# Replace character if it is 1 of a set of characters r

Tags: r, gsub

I have a single column of words that I am trying to clean. Some of the words have characters in them that I would like replaced with a space.

I know how to replace a single character in a string:

```
df2 <- data.frame(gsub("-"," ",data$string_column))
```

This example replaces the '-' character with a space.

How do I apply this procedure to an array of characters? I have tried the following:

```
df2 <- data.frame(gsub(c("-","&")," ",data$string_column))
```

This code runs, but it will only perform the operation of the first character, and not the second.

Any ideas on how to define a list of characters to be replaced by a space?

Thank you

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. It seems like you want `df2 <- data.frame(gsub("[-&]", " ", data$string_column))`. The `gsub` allows for regular expressions so you just need the appropriate regular expression.

Comment: `data$string_column <- gsub("[-&]", " ", data$string_column)`

Answer (score 0):

You need

```r
data$string_column <- gsub("[-&]", " ", data$string_column)
```

This way, all `-` and `&` chars in the `string_column` of the `data` dataframe will get replaced with a space char.